# how to make a form valid if we click the radio button which has compulsory field and clicked another radio button and filling value in that field

Tags: angular

im having a form which is working fine but iam facing a issue ,if i click the client radio button ,it will add the field called select client with dropdown ,but again im changing the radio button from client to vendor now it will show the vendor input field , where iam entering the value and proceeding , when i tried to submit the form is still disabled, i found what is the issue but i couldnt able to find the exact solution .the issue is since i clicked the client radio button which has required field the form is still disabled .can anyone how can we fix this issue.

```
<!-- Select Client or Vendor -->
        <div fxLayout="column" class="create">
            <div class="row">
              <b>Select Client Or Vendor:</b>
              <mat-radio-group class="slip" id="select" formControlName="clientType" >
                <mat-radio-button value="client" class="example-margin">Client</mat-radio-button>
                <mat-radio-button value="vendor" class="example-margin" >Vendor</mat-radio-button>
                <mat-radio-button value="both" class="example-margin">Client/Client's Vendor</mat-radio-button>
              </mat-radio-group>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Select Client -->
          <div fxLayout='column'
            *ngIf="firstFormGroup.controls['clientType'].value=='client' || firstFormGroup.controls['clientType'].value=='both'">
            <!-- Container Recieved -->
            <div fxLayout="column">
                <div class="row">
                  <b>Select Client:</b>
                  <mat-form-field  fxFlex="45"  class="showClient">
                    <mat-select fxFlex placeholder="Company Name"  #companySelect formControlName="companyId" id="companyId" class="form-control"  class="client-adjust" required>
                      <mat-option *ngFor="let company of fetchedCompany" [value]="company.id">{{company.name}}</mat-option>
                         <mat-option (click)="[loadMoreCompanies()]" style="color: blue">
                          Load More
                        </mat-option> 
                    </mat-select>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>
              </div>            
          </div>

          <!-- Select Vendor -->
          <div fxLayout="column" *ngIf="firstFormGroup.controls['clientType'].value=='vendor' || firstFormGroup.controls['clientType'].value=='both'">
              <div class="row">
                <b>Enter Vendor Name:</b>
                <mat-form-field class="qty-received">
                  <input matInput formControlName="vendorName" placeholder="Enter Vendor Name" id="vendorName" type="text"
                    class="form-control" required>
                </mat-form-field>
  <button *ngIf="!editMode && firstFormGroup.controls['purchaseOrder'].value == true" mat-raised-button matStepperNext size="sm" class="mat-green" [disabled]="firstFormGroup.invalid" 
          [ngClass]="{'disable':firstFormGroup.invalid}" (click)="addNewReceivables()"> Create & Continue</button>
```

ts

```
    this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({

      clientType:[''],
      vendorName:[''],
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Custom Validators`.
Firstly please remove `required` from html

```html
<mat-select fxFlex placeholder="Company Name"  #companySelect formControlName="companyId" id="companyId" class="form-control"  class="client-adjust" required> <!-- here -->
<!-- ... -->
<input matInput formControlName="vendorName" placeholder="Enter Vendor Name" id="vendorName" type="text" class="form-control" required> <!-- and from here -->
```

Custom validator which works for you

```js
// your contructor
constructor(_formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.firstFormGroup = _formBuilder.group({
          clientType: ['', Validators.required], // add Validators.required to make sure user always need to select something in radio box
          vendorName: [''],
          companyId: [''],
          purchaseOrder: [true] // I add this only for testing
    });

    this.firstFormGroup.get('clientType').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      if (value === 'client') {
        this.firstFormGroup.get('vendorName').clearValidators();    
        this.firstFormGroup.get('companyId').setValidators(Validators.required);
      } else if (value === 'vendor') {    
        this.firstFormGroup.get('companyId').clearValidators();
        this.firstFormGroup.get('vendorName').setValidators(Validators.required);
      } else if (value === 'both') {
        this.firstFormGroup.get('companyId').setValidators(Validators.required);
        this.firstFormGroup.get('vendorName').setValidators(Validators.required);
      } else {
        this.firstFormGroup.get('companyId').clearValidators();
        this.firstFormGroup.get('vendorName').clearValidators();
      }

      this.firstFormGroup.get('companyId').updateValueAndValidity();
      this.firstFormGroup.get('vendorName').updateValueAndValidity();
    })
   }
```

You can check working example here [stackblitzExample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xagq3n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.ts)

Comment: ,thank you, but  is there any shortcut for this , i know custom validators will solve this issue , but is there any more efficient way to solve this ?

Comment: @ mario89, im still facing the issue, since i clicked the client radio button , the condition becomes true so validators required, even if i click again the vendor

Comment: @ajay I edited stackblitz and my answer, added `clearValidators` for oposit selection case, and `updateValueAndValidity()`

Comment: ,thank you, yeah this works fine, i also added the clearvalidators in the condition ,but  still i faced a issue, what exactly updateValueAndValidity()   is doing here?

Comment: `updateValueAndValidity()` recalculates the value and validation status of the control [official docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updatevalueandvalidity)